# Value of Async Function or Value of HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, httprequest

Good evening,

Im quite new in JavaScript. I want to get the `innerhtml` with `XMLHttpRequest`. The main code works, if I just print the result with `console.log` - I see what I want, but I dont know how to save it as a string, cause I need to work with it. Can you help me out please.

My Code:

```
function getBasketCode(){
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = async function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
            //var code = xhr.responseText;
            var code = document.getElementById("shoppingcart_filled").innerHTML;
            console.log(code); // <-- here it shows me the right result
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.xxxxx.nl/xxxx', true);
    xhr.send();
}
getBasketCode();
```

Comment: 1. have you tried setting it under the `window` object? 2. It looks like, if the `shoppingcart_filled` is updated regardless the request, you still directly use from there any time you wish?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getBasketCode() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = async function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
        var code = document.getElementById("shoppingcart_filled").innerHTML;
        resolve(code);
      }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.xxxxx.nl/xxxx', true);
    xhr.send();
  });
}
const code = await getBasketCode(); // assuming you are in an async function, otherwise getBasketCode().then((code) => {...
```

Comment: it works, thank you very much, could you please explain your last comment "getBasketCode().then((code) => {..." for what do i need .then method in a non async function

Comment: You can only use the await keyword in a functin that is marked `async`. If for some reason you can't do that (there are reasons), or you are in the root scope (not inside a function), then you would need to use the .then syntax instead.

Comment: As this answered your question, please don't forget to mark as answer by clicking the tick on the left (and upvoting, if you like).